# Hibernate @ManyToMany mapping with composite keys

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to map a ManyToMany relationships between 2 tables, both having composite primary keys

```
LSFOCTB which primary key is composed of : LSFOC_CODSOC,LSFOC_CODLSC,LSFOC_CODFOC

LSFORTB which primary key is composed of : LSFOR_CODSOC,LSFOR_CODLSC,LSFOC_CODFOR

The table in charge of the ManyToMany relationship is :

LSFCFTB, with : LSFCF_CODSOC,LSFCF_CODLSC,LSFCF_CODFOC,LSFCF_CODFOR
```

So, in the hibernate model mapping LSFOCTB, I tried :

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = package.LSFOCTB.class, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(name = "LSFCFTB", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "LSFCF_CODLSC", referencedColumnName = "LSFOC_CODLSC"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "LSFCF_CODFOC", referencedColumnName = "LSFOC_CODFOC"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "LSFCF_CODSOC", referencedColumnName = "LSFOC_CODSOC") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "LSFCF_CODLSC", referencedColumnName = "LSFOR_CODLSC"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "LSFCF_CODFOR", referencedColumnName = "LSFOR_CODFOR"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "LSFCF_CODSOC", referencedColumnName = "LSFOR_CODSOC") })
```

before the getter.
But it won't work...
The error, when trying to access the distant collection is :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [beans-dao.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for collection: package.LSFOCTB.distantCollection column: LSFCF_CODLSC
```

Have already managed to make an hibernate mapping work for a ManyToMany relationship ?
If so, what is wrong with my mapping ?
Thank you for your help !

Comment: I've been looking for info on the following pages : http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec chapter : 2.2.5.3.3. Many-to-many

and also : 

http://saloon.javaranch.com/cgi-bin/ubb/ultimatebb.cgi?ubb=get_topic&f=78&t=003838

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are creating a join table with 6 columns and there are duplicate names for your columns. You are actually creating 2 columns with the name **LSFCF_CODLSC** and 2 columns named **LSFCF_CODFOR** and 2 columns named **LSFCF_CODSOC**.

I would suggest that you try this:

```
@JoinTable(name = "LSFCFTB", joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "LSFOC_LSFCF_CODLSC", referencedColumnName = "LSFOC_CODLSC"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "LSFOC_LSFCF_CODFOC", referencedColumnName = "LSFOC_CODFOC"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "LSFOC_LSFCF_CODSOC", referencedColumnName = "LSFOC_CODSOC") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "LSFOR_LSFCF_CODLSC", referencedColumnName = "LSFOR_CODLSC"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "LSFOR_LSFCF_CODFOR", referencedColumnName = "LSFOR_CODFOR"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "LSFOR_LSFCF_CODSOC", referencedColumnName = "LSFOR_CODSOC") })
```

or something similar (according to your naming convention) to give each column a unique name.

Comment: What are the names of the columns in the table named LSFCFTB in the database? name="existing column name" and referencedColumnName="name of column being referenced"